# NSPressGestureRecognizer called before minimumPressDuration

Tags: macos, cocoa, gesture-recognition, nsbutton, long-press

I need my `NSButton` to respond to regular clicks, as well as long presses. I am adding `NSPressGestureRecognizer` like so:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let gr = NSPressGestureRecognizer()
    gr.minimumPressDuration = 1
    gr.action = #selector(handleLongPress)
    button.addGestureRecognizer(gr)  
}

func handleLongPress(gr: NSPressGestureRecognizer) {

    if gr.state == .Began {
        Swift.print("long press")
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, the `handleLongPress` randomly fires even at short single clicks, or double clicks. It happens even if i set the `minimumPressDuration` to higher values.

I have tried playing with the `shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer` but it is not solving the problem.

Is there something i am missing with my code?

Comment: when `state` == `.Began`, the press gesture has **started**. When `state` == `.Ended`, the press gesture has been **recognized**. Change `if gr.state == .Began` to `if gr.state == .Ended`. Read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsgesturerecognizer#1661372).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by handling multiple gesture recognizers:

the class must implement `NSGestureRecognizerDelegate`

```
var singleClick:NSClickGestureRecognizer?
var longClick:NSPressGestureRecognizer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    longClick = NSPressGestureRecognizer()
    longClick!.minimumPressDuration = 1
    longClick!.action = #selector(handleGestureLong)
    longClick!.delegate = self

    singleClick = NSClickGestureRecognizer()
    singleClick?.numberOfClicksRequired = 1
    singleClick!.action = #selector(handleGestureSingle)
    singleClick!.delegate = self

    btn.addGestureRecognizer(longClick!)
    btn.addGestureRecognizer(singleClick!)

}

func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: NSGestureRecognizer, shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: NSGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if gestureRecognizer == singleClick && otherGestureRecognizer == longClick {
        return false
    }
    return true
}

func handleGestureSingle(gr: NSClickGestureRecognizer) {

    switch gr.state {

    case .Ended:
        print("single click")
        break
    default:
        break

    }
}

func handleGestureLong(gr: NSPressGestureRecognizer) {

    switch gr.state {

    case .Began:
        print("long click")
        break
    default:
        break

    }
}
```